# Run HBase inside docker container

Tags: networking, hbase, docker, rpc

I'm trying to setup HBase easily with docker. I have writen the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/tobegit3hub/standalone-hbase-0.94/blob/master/Dockerfile) and run standalone-hbase successfully.

Everything works like a charm within the container. I can implement the Java client to get data from RegionServer as well. But when I move the client outside the container, it doesn't work.

RegionServer seems to open random ports for RPC requests but we can't expose them after running the docker container. I have no idea how to solve it, any suggestion?

Comment: see my answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564097/connect-to-hbase-running-in-docker/28284330#28284330

Comment: The link in question is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like a charm when I start the container with `--net host`.

Comment: Could you share the image that you used and the client code you use to access it? I am using banno/hbase-standalone:latest as the image and using `-net host` when running the container. When I run my client code it throws `default/192.168.99.100:41837` which still seems to be a randomly generated port. Thanks!

Comment: This is a good workaround if you want to run all your containers on the same network as the host. However, the problem remains (resurfaces) when you want to run your containers on another (Docker) network.